# Getting "ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible" for binary classification when I am using "tf.keras.metrics.Recall()"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, bert-language-model

I am working DistillBert project for binary classification. I am trying to run the following code using the Spam SMS data set (You can also use the IMDB dataset, it is also giving the same issue), which runs fine using 'accuracy' and 'sparse_categorical_accuracy' but gives an error when I am using tf.keras.metrics.Recall() or tf.keras.metrics.AUC(). Here I am using the SparseCategoricalCrossentropy loss function and Ada optimizer.

Dataset - The dataset used here is the spam SMS dataset which has binary labels 0 for normal SMS, and 1 for spam SMS. The same error can be reproduced using the IMDB data set for this code.

error -

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

Code -

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import transformers
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
MODEL_NAME = 'distilbert-base-uncased'
BATCH_SIZE = 8
N_EPOCHS = 3

train = pd.read_csv("train_set.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
test = pd.read_csv("test_set.csv", error_bad_lines=False)

X_train = train.text
X_test = test.text
y_train = train.label
y_test = test.label

tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

train_encodings = tokenizer(list(X_train.values),
                        truncation=True, 
                        padding=True)
test_encodings = tokenizer(list(X_test.values),
                       truncation=True, 
                       padding=True)

train_dataset = 
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(train_encodings),list(y_train.values)))

test_dataset = 
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(test_encodings),list(y_test.values)))
test_dataset2 = test_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).take(1000).batch(16)

model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

optimizerr = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)

losss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizerr,
          loss=losss,
          metrics= 
['accuracy','sparse_categorical_accuracy',tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])

print("Evaluate Base model on test data")
results = model.evaluate(test_dataset2)
print("test loss, test acc:", results)
```

How can I get the recall, precision, AUC and other metrics scores for this code?

Edit - When I am using loss function

```
loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
```

The error that I am getting is -

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically don't use sparse categorical cross entropy for a binary classification problem. Just use binary cross entropy. That is most likely why the tensor sizes don't match up.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy

Comment: I made the suggested changes, loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True). I am still getting the error - ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))

Comment: Your metrics also include sparse categorical cross entropy. That needs to be removed. You need the accuracy and recall only.

Comment: This time I removed both sparse categorical accuracy and recall. I am still getting the same error as mentioned in the above comment. - metrics=['accuracy']

Comment: OK, I misread your code. You are using a pretrained BERT model that seems to use one-hot encoding. Your labels are binary so if you want to use a BERT model (I don't know why), you need to encode your ground truth labels with one-hot encoding to make each label of size 2 vs. 1: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot

Comment: This time i used one_hot encoding y_train_encoded=tf.one_hot(y_train.values, 2).  Which was then used to create train_dataset train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(train_encodings),list(y_train_encoded ))). However this time I am getting the following error Function call stack:
test_function -> test_function . What could have gone wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Here is the link for the edited code with one-hot encoding - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73615092/getting-invalid-argument-error-for-binary-classification