# Getting Invalid argument error for Binary classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

I am working on the DistillBert project for binary classification. I am trying to run the following code using the Spam SMS data set (You can also use the IMDB dataset, it is also giving the same issue), I am trying to find out the recall, precision, and AUC score. However, I am getting an Invalid Argument error.

Also, the prediction is like `[-9.,  9.]` . Why is there a negative value here when it is the probability of the class?

Here I am using the `BinaryCrossentropy` loss function and `Adam` optimizer.

Dataset: The dataset used here is the spam SMS dataset which has binary labels 0 for normal SMS and 1 for spam SMS. The same error can be reproduced using the IMDB data set for this code.

Error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: predictions must be >= 0
Condition x >= y did not hold.
First 3 elements of x:
[-9.  9. -9.]
First 1 elements of y:
[0.]
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import transformers
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
MODEL_NAME = 'distilbert-base-uncased'
BATCH_SIZE = 8
N_EPOCHS = 3

train = pd.read_csv("train_set.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
test = pd.read_csv("test_set.csv", error_bad_lines=False)

X_train = train.text
X_test = test.text
y_train = train.label
y_test = test.label

#One-hot encoding of labels
y_train_encoded = tf.one_hot(y_train.values, 2)
y_test_encoded = tf.one_hot(y_test.values, 2)

tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

train_encodings = tokenizer(list(X_train.values),
                        truncation=True, 
                        padding=True)
test_encodings = tokenizer(list(X_test.values),
                       truncation=True, 
                       padding=True)

train_dataset = 
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(train_encodings),list(y_train_encoded)))

test_dataset = 
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(test_encodings),list(y_test_encoded)))
test_dataset2 = test_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).take(1000).batch(16)

model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

optimizerr = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)

losss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy((from_logits=True)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizerr,
          loss=losss,
          metrics=['accuracy'])

print("Evaluate Base model on test data")
results = model.evaluate(test_dataset2)
print("test loss, test acc:", results)

model.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(len(X_train)).batch(BATCH_SIZE),
      epochs=N_EPOCHS,
      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

predictions = model.predict(test_dataset2)
# predictions = TFSequenceClassifierOutput(loss=None, logits=array([[-8.96754 ,  8.966875],....[-8.970767,  8.975923]], dtype=float32), hidden_states=None, attentions=None)

import numpy as np
rounded_predictions = np.rint(predictions.logits)
# rounded_predictions = array([[-9.,  9.],....[-9.,  9.]], dtype=float32)

y_test_encoded
#y_test_encoded = <tf.Tensor: shape=(1930, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[1., 0.],....[0., 1.]], dtype=float32)>

m = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
m.update_state(y_test_encoded, rounded_predictions)
m.result().numpy()
# This is where I getting the above mentioned error.
```

How can I fix the error and get the recall, precision and AUC scores?

Comment: To get recall, precision, and AUC, you need predicted labels and ground truth labels. `evaluate()` doesn't provide predictions. You probably need to use `.predict()` then round the result with `np.rint()` If you're actually doing predictions, that code is missing from your question, and similarly, the problem code referenced in the error might be missing from your question.

Comment: Which function is used in the last layer of your model?

Comment: @Djinn As suggested by you I did use the model.predict() and rounded it using np.rint(). However when I am using the predicted values and true values to get then recall score I am getting the InvalidArgument error. How can I fix this and get the recall and prediction scores?

Comment: Prediction classes typically natural numbers. For example, a binary classifier on cats and dogs would have the classes represented as 0 and 1. The model should be trained on similarly labeled classes, but you're getting negative predictions, such as in your rounded predictions. What does a sample of your labels look like?

Comment: @Djinn the original label is y_test ```y_test.shape``` - (1930,). with values - ```array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1])```. Then I did the one hot encoding in both train and test labels ```y_test_encoded = tf.one_hot(y_test.values, 2)```. Now the values are - ```<tf.Tensor: shape=(1930, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       ...,
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]], dtype=float32)>```.  This is used to create ```test_dataset``` and  then used in ```m.update_state``` as ground truth label

Comment: Do you need the `.logits` call from predictions? If you don't specifically need it, try without.

Comment: @Djinn Even with out the .logits call to preictions. The value of prediction is ```TFSequenceClassifierOutput(loss=None, logits=array([[-8.96754 ,  8.966875],....[-8.970767,  8.975923]], dtype=float32), hidden_states=None, attentions=None)```. And I also removed logits from ```rounded_predictions = np.rint(predictions.logits)``` which I used to get the prediction value array, I got the following error - ```TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type TFSequenceClassifierOutput which has no callable rint method```

Comment: Can you update the question with the result of `model.summary()`? I think you're not using the output of the final, output (classifier) layer, but a layer before that. The error you're getting doesn't match your labels or how the predictions *should* look given the input data.